# get timezone of Google Calendar via Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API to insert events in my customers Google Calendars. I want to insert events in the timezone of their calendar but currently I can only use one timezone via the Google Calendar API.

How can I get the timezone of a specific Google Calendar using the Google Calendar API?

By now I'm using the following code to add an event to a Google Calendar:

```
$eventName='You have ListingAppointments.com Appointment';
$Address='testing-456';
$Ausers='test48@gmail.com';

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    //print_r($events);
    $event = new Google_Event();
    $event->setSummary($eventName);
    $event->setLocation('testing234');

    $start = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2013-07-19T10:25:00.000-07:00');
    //print_r($start);
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_EventDateTime('2013-07-19T10:25:00.000-07:00');
    $end->setDateTime($end);
    //print_r($end);
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail($Ausers);
    $attendees = array($attendee1);
    $event->attendees = $attendees;
    $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);
    print_r($createdEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this code a try:-
`$calendar = $cal->calendars->get('primary');`
`echo $calendar->getTimeZone();`

line one gets you the primary calendar and line  two gets you the timezone using getTimeZone() method.

or simply `$cal->calendars->get('primary')->getTimezone();`

Comment: getting this error  Call to a member function getTimezone() on a non-object in /home/content/70/8448970/html/test.com/wp-content/themes/renegade/google_calendar.php on line 199

Comment: try this `$cal->calendars->get('primary')->getTimezone();`

Comment: are you setting up the client library correctly? try setting up the library again, i guess you might be missing something there. check the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup

Comment: I am including following files require_once 'google/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

Comment: I have checked files both library files does not exist. Can you please send me the library link in which apiclient.php  and  apiCalendarService.php exist ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33858/discussion-between-user1734190-and-karanbir-singh)